# How do i process the Django POST method without form. Getting error - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, post

Am looking to build a view function to which data-JSON can be posted and do some action. Example View function is something like this:

```
def post_data_url(request):
    print("It is also not printing when using POST method!!")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

When i call this url using curl on terminal:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:5000/post_url/
```

Am getting CSRF token missing error. Am not using any form at all! Why do i need to include csrf token everytime? In Python-Flask, Am able do it with ease.

Comment: use **csrf_exempt**, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `csrf_exempt` decorator:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `{% csrf_token %}` somewhere near the form. ( in your view)

This will help django to keep a token in a hidden element. When Django POSTs, it will check with this token value to validate your POST.